# In my pl/SQL code there is an error which states that "The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned" any ideas

Tags: sql, plsql

This is my PL/SQL error:

> Error report
>
> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
> ORA-06512: at line 67
>
> 1422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>       *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>       *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

PL/SQL script:

```
DECLARE
cursor cur is (select distinct sor_ident
from CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_polices, CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_sit_objet_risque, CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_produitass, cleva_owner_be.f_desc_stat_100, CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_p_c_client, CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_garantie_dyn
where pol_ident = sor_ptrpolid
and sor_ident = d100_ptrsorid 
and bpcl_ident = pol_ptrclid
and pol_ptrpasid = pas_ident
and sor_ident = gad_ptrsorid
and pas_code_produit IN ('BFOV','BFOV2','BFOV5','BFOV6')
and BPCL_LIB24 = '1'
and d100_lib01 IN ('1','2','4','5','6')
and d100_lib09 > '1997'
and ( pol_codetat in ('1', '3', '6') or ( pol_codetat = '0' and pol_datcre > trunc ( sysdate - 183 ) ) )
and gad_code IN('RCVVY','RCLTY','RCVCT','RCHTY') 
);
type tt_cur is varray(50) of cur%rowtype;
t_cur tt_cur;
type tt_cld is varray(50) of CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn%rowtype;
t_cld tt_cld := tt_cld();
cld_key pls_integer;
v_ordre varchar2(3900);
v_desc varchar2(5000);
v_titre varchar2(5000);
BEGIN
t_cld.extend();
t_cld(1).CLD_IDENT           := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_PTRSORID        := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_TEXTE           := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_ORDRE           := null;          
t_cld(1).CLD_CODE            := 'RCVT7';
t_cld(1).CLD_SEQUENTIEL      := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_SERVICES        := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_INT_LOT_IMP     := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_INT_LOT_EXP     := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_LIBRE            := 0;
t_cld(1).CLD_CHAPITRE         := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_S_CHAPITRE      := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_SS_CHAPITRE     := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_TYPE             := 2;
t_cld(1).CLD_TABLE             := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_REFECHO          := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_PTRSARID         := null;
t_cld(1).CLD_TITRE             := null;
t_cld.extend(49,1); 
 
 
Line 67   select nvl( max(CLD_ident), 30000000) into cld_key
          from CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn
          where CLD_ident between 30000000 and 49999999;
 
 
 
select TGA_ORDRE, tga_description, tga_titre into v_ordre, v_desc, v_titre
from cleva_owner_be.f_tarif_gar
where TGA_CODE = 'RCVT7';
 
 
OPEN cur;
LOOP
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO t_cur LIMIT 50 ;
    FOR i IN 1 .. t_cur.COUNT
      LOOP
      cld_key := cld_key + 1;
      t_cld(i).CLD_IDENT := cld_key;
      t_cld(i).CLD_PTRSORID := t_cur(i).sor_ident;
     t_cld(i).CLD_TEXTE := v_desc;
      t_cld(i).CLD_TITRE := v_titre;
        t_cld(i).CLD_ORDRE := v_ordre;
    END LOOP;
    FORALL j IN 1..t_cur.COUNT
       INSERT INTO CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn VALUES t_cld(j);
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND ;
END LOOP;
END
;
```

Comment: Which line of your PL/SQL code is line 67?

Comment: This looks very much like it could be done in a single insert statement. Is there a reason you're doing it like this (e.g. homework around collections)? Also, in general, it's bad to commit inside a loop around a cursor; you could be opening yourself up to a snapshot-too-old error.

Comment: select nvl( max(CLD_ident), 30000000) into cld_key
  from CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn
 where CLD_ident between 30000000 and 49999999;

Comment: THis part is line 67 that start with select nvl(max...

Comment: pls_integer can only hold one value from select. Your select statement is clearly fetching more then one records, thats why select into is failing. you may want to change the declaration of cld_key pls_integer;
or limit the records in your select statement select nvl( max(CLD_ident), 30000000) into cld_key
          from CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn
          where CLD_ident between 30000000 and 49999999 
and ROWNUM = 1;

Comment: I try select nvl( max(CLD_ident), 30000000) into cld_key from CLEVA_OWNER_BE.f_clause_dyn where CLD_ident between 30000000 and 49999999 and ROWNUM = 1; but did not work

Comment: I change the cld_key pls_intege to binary still does not work

Comment: that's an aggregate query anyway, so it's unlikely to be the cause of the error. Are you absolutely sure that's the line causing the problem? I suspect it's much more likely to be the next query on `cleva_owner_be.f_tarif_gar` that's the problem statement, unless `TGA_CODE` is the primary key of that table?